# Does newBuilder() from Protobuf generated classes create a new Java object?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Does `newBuilder()` creates a new Java object? It doesn't seem like to be the case for my quick test. Calling `.hashcode()` on 2 different objects, it has the same hash code.

```java
import com.mydomain.proto.users.api.User;

...

User a = User.newBuilder().setUserUuid("1111111111").build();
User b = User.newBuilder().setUserUuid("1111111111").build();

System.out.println("a hashcode: " + a.hashCode());
System.out.println("b hashcode: " + b.hashCode());

// assertNotEquals fails.
assertNotEquals(a.hashCode(), b.hashCode());
```

Printing them out and see that the hash code is the same, though I am expecting a new Java object.

```
a hashcode: 611667980
b hashcode: 611667980
```

Note, we are using this

```
'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.12.0'
```

Comment: You need to look at the generated `User` class and see how it implements hashCode

Comment: Same hashCode does not imply object identity. See the Javadoc. You need to test object identity with `==`.

Comment: The question relies on an assumption which is contradicted in the Javadoc.

Comment: @user207421 yes, I agree on that. But it's an usual mistake to think each object has its own unique hashcode, hence, thinking same hashcodes means same identity `this==that`. Sharing hashcodes doesn't even imply equality, as you said. *But OP has the right to be confused*

Comment: @aran It's not a 'usual mistake' at all. It betrays a fundamental misunderstanding of hashing. Questions based on false assumptions aren't real questions and don't belong here.

Comment: @user207421 one thing is for sure, you'd be a tough professor ...  ; )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implication of the hashcode and same (==) is not bidirectional.

Two objects that are the same object, or own the same contents, should have the same hashcode.

Two objects sharing the same hashcode doesn't imply they're the same object.

In order to test this, check

```
System.out.println(a==b);
```

It will print `false`, **because they are different Objects**, even if they share the same hashcode.

Source code for `Message`:

[image]

`Equals` check first if the objects are indeed the same (`==`) . If not, checks if their fields and properties *contain the same values*.

`Hashcode` will output the same value if two objects *contain the same properties and fields*. **Regardless they're the same object (`other==this`) or not**. Just like Strings do.

This is what Java Object's [**hashCode()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) tells:

[image]

---

***Example with Strings***

```
String s1 = new String("Yepp");  //hashcode = 2752044
String s2 = new String("Yepp");  //hashcode = 2752044
String s3 = s1;                  //hashcode = 2752044
```

All share the same hashcode. But there are two different Objects here:
`s1/s3` and `s2`.

```
System.out.println(s1==s2);   // false
System.out.println(s1==s3);   // true
System.out.println(s1.hashCode()==s2.hashCode()); //true
```

That's why is an usual mistake comparing two strings with the `==` operator. This is not checking the values, but the object reference.

If the class overrides equals, (as Strings do), it will tell you they're equal objects: Equal as twins may be, but twins are two anyway.

```
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // true
```

---

**Resume**: **Yes, it's creating new objects**. The values inside are meaningless, and sharing the same hashcode only means they both have the same contents *(and that their hashcode algorithm works well*)

Comment: Thanks, so does using `.equals()` better ? Does it compare every field inside each object

Comment: @xbeta in resume: if you want to check if they're the SAME object, use `==` . If you want to check if they have the same values (as in your example), use `equals`, as proto messages override this and compare fields. But most important: **1-same hashcode does not necessarilly  imply same object.** **2-equals=true does not necessarilly imply same object**

Comment: Got it, will use `equals()` for my case. Thanks!

Comment: Good job! Keep up the good work!